# Why am I not able to load files from a partition with U-Boot?

Tags: partition, embedded, sd-card, u-boot, fat32

For some reason, my U-Boot does not seem to be able to load files from my FAT32 partition:

```
=> mmc part

Partition Map for MMC device 1  --   Partition Type: DOS

Part    Start Sector    Num Sectors     UUID            Type
  1     2048            62519296        a1d1165e-01     0b
=> fatls mmc 1:1
    52560   file1.bin
     1984   file2.bin
      456   file3.bin
       64   file4.bin
=> fatload mmc 1:1 0x0001FF80 file1.bin
** Reading file would overwrite reserved memory **
Failed to load 'file1.bin'
```

Why do I get `Failed to load` and how can I get around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's telling you the reason:

```
** Reading file would overwrite reserved memory **
```

Based on the first line of the error message, reading the file into memory using the start address you specified would cause some reserved memory area to be overwritten.

You should either use a different start address (and perhaps rebuild your file(s) to match the changed start address), or perhaps change U-Boot (and rebuild it) to place itself into a different location if U-Boot is the one reserving the memory you are trying to use.

You will have to understand the boot-time memory map of the system you're trying to boot. Without knowing the actual hardware you're using, it's kind of difficult to help you there, but [the `bdinfo` command of U-Boot](https://www.denx.de/wiki/DULG/UBootCmdGroupInfo) could be a good starting point.